# Trigger deleting data periodically

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'd like to have the trigger that removes some rows in given table as given time (e.g. 10 am every day) comes. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Full SQL Server**

Instead of a trigger you can set your code in a stored procedure, and define an scheduled job to call that sp every day at 10am.

You create the job :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job

Its command has to be a call to your cleaning sp, something like :

```
exec (your stored proc name) (and possibly add parameters)
```

And you schedule it to be called once per day :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job

**SQL Server Express**

Since you have SQL Server Express and can't use the SQL Server Agent, you can instead use the task scheduler of Windows itself to call your cleaning code once per day.

Create an script file **cleaning.sql** with your delete commands, and create also a batch file **cleaning.bat** to execute it. Example of the batch file :

```
sqlcmd -i cleaning.sql
```

Put those two files on the same folder and set the task scheduler to execute that batch every day at 10am.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use jobs and schedules because my sql server doesn't have sql server agent (it's express verison). So how do deal with the task?

Comment: I will edit my answer to also cover SQL Server Express, check it in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that option should be ok.
Anyway, I'm also interested if there is way to specify a trigger that would do the same actions. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: No, sorry, as far as I know you can't achieve that with Triggers.